# Build an OR gate where the output is fed into the input B

Tags: transistors, logic-gates, circuits

I want to make this logic gate.

[image]

It is basically an OR gate where the output is connected to input B. I want to make it using transistors and a breadboard.

[image]

The images show my attempt.

The problem is the output doesn’t stay on high if I stop pressing the button. I really don’t know what the problem is.

Maybe you can help?

Edit: I hope the schematic will help.

[image]

---

Thanks to all of you who tried to help me. I guess the way I imagined the oa to work isn’t right. So maybe I should start from the bottom.

I saw this circuit at a YouTube video from Ben eater about sr latches. He uses a 74LS32 chip, which contains 4 or gates. One of them is used in the circuit. I thought I could just build a standard or gate from resistors (the circuit is from the video „logic gates using transistors“ from Ben eater) and then act like it is the or gate from the chip. This was my try. Can anyone explain why this didn’t work? Are there differences in t or gates or something?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bs1R.png)

Comment: Please draw a schematic. We can't even know what transistors those are so we don't know if they are wired correctly.

Comment: I can try to draw a schematic, if it helps the transistors are PN 2222A NPN transistors

Comment: The circuit is likely to be of little use. If the output goes high on power-on the circuit will latch and stay that way until power is cycled again. If it doesn't then the circuit will latch when the button is pressed until power is cycled again taking you back to the hit-and-miss power up sequence.

Comment: I know this circuit doesn’t has much use I just want to understand how it could work. The plan is to have a circuit that once the button is pressed will stay with a high output until I cut of the power.

Comment: Are you intending to use the transistors in reverse here?

Comment: The transistors in the schematic are upside down. Use the built-in schematic editor so you don't have to redraw the circuit with a pen and post another picture.

Comment: Yes but Would it make a difference? I’m pretty new to this btw

Comment: @justme im on mobile so Its a lot of pain to use schematic editors

Comment: Of course it would matter which way they are in a circuit. They way it is now drawn would never light up the LED as no current would flow the wrong way via a transistor (under normal operating conditions).

Comment: @Justme:  Transistors will work if you swap the collector and emitter - they just don't work well.

Comment: @UbahnUlrich:  The "Answer" you just posted is not an answer.  Add the new information to the end of your question, and then delete the non-Answer.  This isn't a forum where you just keep posting things to the end.  Answers aren't even shown in the order they were posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your transistors are backwards, at least in your schematic.  I don't know if you really installed them backwards.

Transistors will work if you swap the emitter and collector, they just don't work well.  Normally, the collector current of a small switching transistor will be around 100 times the base current.  If you swap the collector and emitter, then the collector current will only be about 10 times the base current.  The current gain (amplification) is much lower when you swap the emitter and collector as you diagram shows it.

Your diagram should look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfAUW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Besides having the transistors backwards, you also needed resistors in the base connections of the transistors.

I don't know if this will actually do what you expect it to.

When I simulated it, the output followed the input just as you described your non-working circuit.  You seem to be expecting it to latch to high, but that circuit can't latch.

You can build a simple latch using two transistors [as this earlier question shows.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227482/sr-flip-flop-with-2-npn-transistors-initial-state)

[image]

Grounding one input momentarily causes the active LED to change - the selected LED will then stay on.  Grounding the other input will change the selected LED back to the other one - and it will stay.

You could leave out one LED and one switch, and have the remaining LED  latch on when you press the button.  It'll be a little tricky to make it work right, though.  There is no determined state at power on.  You might have to replace the removed LED with a resistor or a diode to make the remaining LED always be off when you connect the circuit to the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

You have shorted the base and emitter of the rightmost transistor, so Vbe is always 0V, Ib is always 0, and the transistor will always be off.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies, do u have a idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe, but the question was what was wrong in the original circuit, not how to fix it, so that would be another question. Suggesting any fixes would most likely end up with a circuit that you can't build with the components you have. So you should also list what components you have so we can build a circuit with those components.